# Datepicker on codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, datepicker

I have Datepicker that is purely working in test_datepicker.html. Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
       <title>Date Picker</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" >
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
         $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        });
       </script>
     </head>
     <body>
```

this is working, but when i sync this on my ci with php the code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it... :) cheers

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();      
</script>
```

---

When i check it on my Dev tools in my google Chrome, it does not recognize as a function..

Answer (score 0):

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" ?>' >
    http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" ?>' >

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" ?>' >

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

---

```
<table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th class="author">Employee</th>
                <th>Branch</th>
                <th>Designation</th>
                <th>Date hired</th>
            </tr>

            <?php

            $e = $this->db->distinct("lastname,firstname")->from("tb_employee")->get();
            foreach($e->result() as $emp ):

            ?>               
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $emp->lastname . ' ' . $emp->firstname; ?></td>

                <td>
                    <select name = "tbarnch">
                    <?php $b = $this->db->select("*")->from("tb_branch")->get();
                    foreach($b->result() as $br ):
                    ?>
                        <option value =<?php echo $br->branch_id;?>>
                          <?php echo $br->branch_name; ?> 
                        </option>
                    <?php endforeach;?> 
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <select name = "tdesignation">
                    <?php $d = $this->db->select("*")->from("tb_designation")->get();
                    foreach($d->result() as $des ):
                    ?>
                        <option>
                          <?php echo $des->designation_name; ?> 
                        </option>
                    <?php endforeach;?> 
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td>
                <select>
                    <?php 
                    $date = '';
                    $date = date("Y");

                        for ($i=$date; $i > 1900;$i--) { 
                            echo "<option value = ".$i.">" .$i. "</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Pickup Date" id="datepicker"  name="datepicker"></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>                   
        </table>
```

---

i am using table tag on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to paste the following code before the body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
         $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: i have already put that script tag before my body tag still dont work and i have also tried put the script tag before the </body> close tag.